# How do I restrict my driver from working for thirdparty applications?

Tags: c#, device-driver

How do I restrict my webcam driver from being used by other applications?
I don't want other applications to use it. It should only work with my application.

Anyway I can achieve this in C#? The driver is developed by a different company and we're just getting the software done.

I understand that its not fair to ask the entire code..But atleast point me please.

Thanks so much.

Comment: The customer is building his own proprietary hardware and he wants the hardware to only work with his software. Do we have a choice? :) now I'll have to leave this part to the driver development company.

Comment: The customer in this case needs to be informed that their request is nonsensical. What they're asking for is basically the same as this kind of crap: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_copy_protection_rootkit_scandal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without rewriting the driver, adding a bunch of checks that could probably be got around by someone who decompiles the code and sees what they are and duplicates them, or by adding DRM at a driver level, which will annoy users and be a maintenance nightmare? You can't. Device drivers expose a device to the system, not to an individual program.